# Placing form elements into a table using HTML

Tags: html

Is there a way to place the user's HTML form selections into a table? So, say they select the first option "Apples" from the drop down menu labled "Favorite Fruits". "Apples" would then appear in a table on the same page. Any help is greatly appreciated.
EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT TO DO:
I have the following drop down menu. The user selects his or her favorite game, and when they do a new div appears asking why. Each selection must get printed in a table. I am not sure how.

```
<tr><td>
<script>

var sections = {
    'TF2': 'section2',
'why': 'section3',  
};  
var selection = function(select) {

for(i in sections)
    document.getElementById(sections[i]).style.display = "none";    

document.getElementById(sections[select.value]).style.display = "block";

}

</script>
<form id="survey" action="#" method="post">
<tr><td><div id="section1" style="display:block;">
    <label for="game">Select Your Favorite Game</label>
    <select id="game" onchange="selection(this);">
                <option disabled selected>Choose</option>
        <option value="TF2">TF2</option>
        <option value="LoL">League of Legends</option>
        <option value="Minecraft">Minecraft</option>
    </select>
</div></tr></td>

<tr><td><div id="section2" style="display:none;">
    <label for="type">Why do you like it?:</label>
    <select id="type" onchange="selection(this);">
                        <option disabled selected>Options</option>
        <option value="fun">Fun</option>
        <option value="easy">Easy</option>
        <option value="difficult">Difficult</option>
    </select>
        </div></tr></td>
```

And I want to display the user's selection in a table on the page. Any ideas?

Comment: You will need to use javascript.

Comment: Have a look at the jQuery library and the onchange() function http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I was thinking javascript. How would one implement this?

Comment: I just updated my question. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2CxeU/) fiddle I just created.  It should get you going.

I have almost no experience with jquery and was able to figure it out quickly, based on the link provided by @Billy Moat above as well as [this one](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) on `:selected`